# Looking for a reference: nested Hilbert spaces methods for abstract evolution (variational) problems

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, distribution-theory

Let $V,H$ be infinite dimensional separable Hilbert spaces such that $V \hookrightarrow H \hookrightarrow V^*$, where each space is continuously injected in the next one with density. We define:

$$ H(V) := H(a,b ; V, V^*) := \{ u \in L^2(a,b ; V) : u' \in L^2(a,b ; V^*) \} $$

Fix $u_0 \in H$ and $f \in L^2(a,b ; V^*)$. We can set up the problem: find $u \in H(V)$ such that

\begin{aligned}
 \frac{d}{dt} & \langle u(t), v \rangle_{V^* \times V} + a(u(t),v) = \langle f(t),v \rangle_{V^* \times V} \\
&u(0)=u_0
\end{aligned}
for all $v \in V$. Where $a(\cdot , \cdot )$ is a continuous bilinear form (possibly depending on time) on $V \times V$.

I would be grateful if anyone could provide a reference for the study of existance and uniqueness for this type of problems in this abstract framework, maybe just in the easier case $ V \hookrightarrow H$ (with the necessary modifications). Thank you in advance.